# SwiftUI does not perform onInsert when the list is empty?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 lists on the UI, 1 list is allow user to drag to another list. I have problem when the 
"selected product list" is empty. It does not perform the .onInsert function.

It have no problem when the array "selectedProduct" is not empty when it was rendering.

How can i to allow user to drag and drop when the other list is completely empty?

```
List(selection: $selection)
{
     HStack(alignment: .center)
     {
       Spacer().frame(width: 200)
       Text("Product Name")
           .foregroundColor(blue)
           .lineLimit(1)
       Spacer()
       Text("Price")
           .foregroundColor(blue)
       Spacer()
       Text("Unit")
            .foregroundColor(blue)
       Spacer()
      }

   ForEach(selectedProduct, id:\.id)
   {
       rider in
       SelectedProductView()    
   }
   .onInsert(of: ["public.data"])
   {
       self.addProduct(position: $0, itemProviders: $1, top: true)
   }
}
```

Comment: i would propose you copy reproducable copyable code in here so we can try out...with just one list we cannot reproduce your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.onInsert` works on `DynamicViewContent`, so when your `selectedProduct` is empty there is no content, so nowhere to insert.

There two possibilities as I see to solve this situation:

1) implement support for drop on List and make it active when `selectedProduct` is empty to make possible to `add` first element in dynamic content

2) implement *stub* product-item (like, empty row showing "drop here" text) that is explicitly added to `selectedProduct` when it becomes empty of real products, thus making content not empty to allow standard `.onInsert` work for you.